# Linked list static class members

Tags: c++, pointers, static, linked-list

So, to begin I want to say that I'm doing this to learn, that's why I'm not using a Standard Library container.

I have a class representing a widget in a Qt Ui. These widgets can be deleted or new ones can be added at the end of the list, that's why they are in a linked list. The class looks like this:

```
class Item
{
    static Item* first_item;
    static Item* last_item;
    Item* prev_item;
    Item* next_item;

    public:
    Item(MainWindow*, bool);
    ~Item();              
}
```

My problem is that if I want to have multiple linked lists of this type (say two different lists of widgets), the static pointers to the `first_item` and `last_item` nodes will be the same for all lists, which is bad. I had the idea to give the first and last pointer as a constructor parameter, so a newly created `Item` knows which list it belongs to.

This seems ugly to me, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: make every list have private item, and root of the list (other things to simplify implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to separate the list itself (which needs to know the first and last item, and the item (which doesn't).

```
class List
{
    class Item  // This is private to List, so List automatically has access
                // to its internals.
    {
        Item* prev_item;
        Item* next_item;
        T Value;          // Presumably each item in the list has some sort
                          // of value;
    }
    Item* first_item;
    Item* last_item;
public:
    List(...);  // Constructor as appropriate
    ~List();
    List(const List& rhs) = delete;            // Need a copy constructor 
    List& operator=(const List& rhs) = delete; // and copy assignment operator.
}
```

If you want to be able to copy or assign lists, you'll need to actually implement the appropriate function rather than `= delete` them.

If you want each `Item` to remember the `List` it belongs to, you could add a reference back to the owner.

```
class List
{
    class Item  // This is private to List, so List automatically has access
                // to its internals.
    {
        Item* prev_item;
        Item* next_item;
        T value;          // Presumably each item in the list has some sort
                          // of value;

        const List& owner;// Back reference.
        Item(const List& owner_) : owner(owner_) {}
    }
    Item* first_item;
    Item* last_item;
public:
    List(...);  // Constructor as appropriate
    List(const List& rhs) = delete;
    List& operator=(const List& rhs) = delete;
    ~List();
}
```

Of course, if the `Item` remembers its owner, that makes copy and assignment much trickier.

Comment: Yeah, I won't have to copy or assign anything, so no worries there :)

Comment: Always worth deleting the relevant functions though.  That way the compiler will tell you if you accidentally write something that involves either.  Note in particular, "no copy/assign" means "no function returning `List`" too.  That can be fixed by adding a move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

can you check without declaring them `static`? I think `static` is the issue. A `static` member is "one per class". I think a better way to do this is to initialize them to with value in a constructor (may be assign default value as well).

Read this to know more about the `static` keyword: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

possibly related threads : [C++ class with static pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033649/c-class-with-static-pointer) and  [Initializing a static pointer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620408/initializing-a-static-pointer-in-c)

Comment: But then I have one `first` and `last` pointer per object, isn't that inefficient?

Comment: well kindof, depends on your demands. A pointer is a few bytes (depending on your system) so it is using memory indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Having an attribute that's pointing to the **first** of the list is probably cause you a problem. Because the **first** may change later and every time it does you have to update the **first** pointer for all elements in that list.

If you have multiple lists, then store a list of first pointers (list of lists):

```
// Each element in the list is head of a linked list    
std::vector<Item*> itemLists;
```

Vector here is used for simplicity. You can easily declare another class for a list of "item list" such as:

```
class List
{
    Item *first;
    //Item *last; // you may also want to know the last.
    List *nextList, *prevList;
};
```

By the way, since it's a doubly linked list, you could create a function that returns the first and last for each item:

```
Item *first()
{
   if(prev_item != NULL)
       return prev_item->first();
   return this;
}

Item *last()
{
   if(next_item != NULL)
      return next_item->last();
   return this;
}
```

To sum up, do not use a static attribute. Also an element does not need to know it's first (yet, it can reach to it's first with a simple function). It would be a waste of memory. The outer class, that uses the list, needs to know the first (and/or last depending on your needs).